Does the strict inequality in the Layer Cake Representation Matter?
I have seen both version of layer cake representation theorem stated:
Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space $f: \Omega \to [0, \infty]$-measurable function. Then the function $x \in [0, \infty] \to \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \})$ is Borel measurable and (Version 1)
$$
\int_\Omega f \,d\mu = \int_0 ^\infty \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \}) \,dx.
$$
or (Version 2)
$$
\int_\Omega f \,d\mu = \int_0 ^\infty \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) \,dx.
$$
Now going through the proof, which is just a simply application of Fubini's, I think we can conclude both of the versions to be correct (?) as Lebesgue measures have point mass zero. I wonder if I could get some confirmation on if this is true: I will write the proof for the weak inequality here, one can imagine substituting strict inequality everywhere and it seems like everything should go through?
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x) d \mu(x) 
= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{[0, f(x)]}(t) dt d \mu(x)
= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{f(x) \geq t}(x) d \mu (x) dt
= \int_0^\infty \mu \left ( \{ x : f(x) \geq t \} \right ) dt.
$$
Now if this was the case, then it seems to suggest if $f$ is integrable, we must have
$$
\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) = \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \})
$$
for Lebesgue almost every $x$, which seems to be a nice little corollary, but I wonder if there is a better way to show this instead of invoking the Layer cake representation?
Update:
This is my attempt of a proof for the second question and I wonder if I could get some suggestions on if the proof is correct:
Note that for Lebesgue almost every $x \geq 0$, we have $\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \}) = \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \})$. To see this, it suffices to note $\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x \}) > 0$ for at most countably many $x \geq 0$. The function $x \mapsto \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \})$ is a monotone function as $x_1 \geq x_2 \implies \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x_1 \}) \leq \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x_2 \})$. Therefore, the function $x \mapsto \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \})$ has at most countably many jump discontinuities. In particular, note if $\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x' \}) > 0$ for some $x'$, then $x \mapsto \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \})$ has a jump discontinuity at $x'$. Indeed, let $x_n \to x'$ from the left hand side increasing. Let $\{ A_k \}_{k = 1} ^\infty$ be increasing sequence of $\mu$-finite set from $\sigma$-finiteness. Choose $k$ large enough so that $A_k \cap \{ \omega: f(\omega) > x' \} \not= \emptyset$. Then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x_n \} \cap A_k) = \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x' \} \cap A_k).
$$
Moreover, let $x_n' \to x'$ from the right hand side decreasing, then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x_n' \}) = \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x' \}).
$$
Therefore, we have that
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x_n \}) &= \lim_{k \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x_n \} \cap A_k) \\
    &= \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x' \}) \\
    &> \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x' \}) \\
    &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x_n' \}).
\end{align*}
Note this shows that $x'$ is a point of jump discontinuity. In particular, we then must have $\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \}) = \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \})$ for Lebesgue almost every $x$ as it must be except from at most countably many points from the above discussion.

Both are correct. I didn't check your specific proofs.

Regarding the first question: yes, both versions are correct. See the remark at the end of this answer.
Regarding the second question: in fact, we can prove a stronger result.

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f: \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ a measurable function. If $f$ is integrable, then there is a countable set $D \subseteq [0, \infty]$ such that, for all $x \in [0, \infty] \setminus D$,
$$
\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) = \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \})
$$

Proof:
Since $\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \} = \{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \} \cup \{ \omega: f(\omega) = x \}$ and $\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \} \cap \{ \omega: f(\omega) = x \}= \emptyset$, we have that
$$
\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) = \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \}) + \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x \})
$$
So, if $\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) \neq \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \})$, then $\mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x \}) \neq 0$.
In other words, let $D = \{ x \in [0, \infty]  : \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) \neq \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \})\}$ and let $E = \{ x \in [0, \infty]  : \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x \})  \neq 0\}$. Then $D \subseteq E$.
So, we just need to prove that  $E$ is countable.
Let $F = \{ x \in (0, \infty]  : \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x \})  \neq 0\}$. Note that $E \subseteq \{0\} \cup F$. So, all we need is to prove that $F$ is countable.
For each $n \in \Bbb N$, let $F_n = \{ x \in F : x \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x \})  > \frac {1}{n+1}\}$. It is easy to see that $F = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} F_n$.
Now, let $c = \int_\Omega f d\mu < +\infty$. Given $n \in \Bbb N$, suppose there are at least $d$ elements in $F_n$, namely $\{x_j\}_{j \in \{1,...,d\}}$.
Then,
$$
0\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^d x_j \chi_{\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x_j \}} \leqslant f
$$
So, we have
$$
d \frac{1}{n+1} < \sum_{j=1}^d x_j \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) = x_j \}) \leqslant \int_\Omega f d\mu =c <+\infty
$$
So, $d < (n+1) c <+\infty$. It means $F_n$ can not have more than $(n+1) c $ and so it is a finite set.
Since  $F = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} F_n$, we have that $F$ is countable and so $E$ and $D$ are countable.
$\square$
Remark: Using the result above, it is immediate to prove version 2 of the layer cake representation theorem from the version 1.  In fact, if $f$ is not integrable, then
$$
+\infty =\int_\Omega f \,d\mu = \int_0 ^\infty \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \}) \,dx \leqslant \int_0 ^\infty \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) \,dx.
$$
So,
$$
+\infty =\int_\Omega f \,d\mu = \int_0 ^\infty \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \}) \,dx = \int_0 ^\infty \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) \,dx.
$$
If $f$ is integrable, then using the result proved above, we have
$$
\int_\Omega f \,d\mu = \int_0 ^\infty \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) > x \}) \,dx = \int_0 ^\infty \mu(\{ \omega: f(\omega) \geq x \}) \,dx.
$$

Thank you for your answer! Just out of curiosity, I wonder if you could also check my proof provided in the update section? It seems like I have arrived at the same conclusion as you did by using points of discontinuity.

@PartialT Your proof is correct, but it can be simplified / improved. Since $f$ is supposed integrable, you don't need the measure space to be $\sigma$-finite. Since $f$ is integrable, for any $x >0$, $\mu({ \omega: f(\omega) > x })$ is finite.

I see. Thank you!
